# GAS Class SpreadsheetApp : Append Row and Merge Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wish it was this simple but this doesn't work.

```js
sheet.appendRow(['MERGE', '']).merge();
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The method [merge()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) needs to be applied to a range object.

One possibility to do so would be:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var newRow=sheet.getLastRow()+1;
// the range dimensions should match the value array dimensions
  var range=sheet.getRange(newRow,1,1,2);
  range.setValues([['MERGE', '']]);
  range.merge(); 
}
```

References:

- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [merge()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#merge)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow)

Answer (score 0):

**Append Row**

This is just a simple of example of find a row with todays date and appending it to another sheet.  In this example, I also delete the current row in the source sheet this making it more of a move command.

```
function findingRowsAndAppendingToAnotherSheet() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var srg=ssh.getRange(2,1,ssh.getLastRow()-1,ssh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=srg.getValues();
  var cdv=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate()).valueOf();
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var dd=new Date(vA[i][0]);
    var ddv=new Date(dd.getFullYear(),dd.getMonth(),dd.getDate()).valueOf();
    if(ddv==cdv) {
      dsh.appendRow(vA[i]);//Appends row with current date to dsh
      ssh.deleteRow(i+2-d++);//Deletes ssh current row.  Effectively making this a move instead of a copy
    }
  }
}
```

Sheet1 & 2 Before Running

[image]

[image]

Sheet1 & 2 After Running

[image]

[image]